# How to add images using AdminLTE 3 and CodeIgniter PhP Framework

Tags: php, image, codeigniter-3, adminlte

Currently im using CodeIgniter 3 as my PhP Framework and AdminLTE for template, but i don't know how and where to add new image.

My PhP file was on the `C:\xampp\htdocs\mysa_2\application\views\Content` folder using CI3 (extract from CI3), i've also tried create a new img folder in 'Content' but the code still cant detect it.

Comment: please share your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't serve images from inside the `application` folder, since that folder contains an .htaccess file that prevents direct access to its files and subfolders.

Instead, create your `img` folder at the root of your project and add an image to it:

```
mysa_2
  - application
  - img
    image.jpg
  - system
  index.php
```

Then in `application/config/autoload.php` enable the url helper, so you can use the `base_url` function in the view:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

And include the image in the view, like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('img/image.jpg'); ?>">
```